# setting image as data-attributes on Rails Image Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please I need some help here, I want to set image as data-attributes.

This is an example of what I want to achieve.

```
<div class='square' data="https://churchbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/image/5/medium_pastor1.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Date=20170825T160713Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-">
```

but I don't know how to get the right syntax with image upload on Rails.

```
<%= image_tag page_pc.image.url(:large), class:'square' if page_pc.image? %>
```

If any one knows how to get this work or any other alternative, please your help will be very much appreciated.

This is the example of my HTML

```
<div class="square-flip">
    <div class='square' data-image="http://titanicthemes.com/files/flipbox/kallyas-bundle.png">
        <div class="square-container">
            <div class="align-center"><img src="http://titanicthemes.com/files/flipbox/kallyas.png" class="boxshadow" alt=""></div>
            <h2 class="textshadow">Kallyas WordPress Theme</h2>
            <h3 class="textshadow">The #1 Selling Most Enjoyable and Creative Multipurpose WordPress theme.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='square2' data-image="http://titanicthemes.com/files/flipbox/kallyas-bundle.png">
        <div class="square-container2">
            <div class="align-center"></div>
            <a href="http://kallyas.net" target="_blank" class="boxshadow kallyas-button">View Demos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`TagHelper#content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) to create a div, which can have the needed css and data attribute, like:

```
<%= content_tag :div, '', class: 'square', data: { image: image } %>
```

Which prints:

```
<div class="square" data-image="image"></div>
```

To access your images in the assets folder then you can use `asset_path`:

```
<%= content_tag :div, '', class: 'square', data: { image: asset_path('image.jpg') } %>
```

If you need to add content inside your content_tag, then you can pass a block as its last parameter, as it's specified:

```
content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
```

So you can try with:

```
<%= content_tag :div, '', class: 'square', data: { image: asset_path('image.jpg') } do %>
  <div class="square-container">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Anyways you can just do something similar without using content_tag, like:

```
<div class="square" data-image="<%= asset_path('image.jpg') %>">
  <div class="square-container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, it worked but the only challenge i am now facing is the div, the syntax u used for the div gave it open and closing div but it needed to be inside an opening div only, while the closing div will be placed under to cover other contents and elements. the image is showing now with the example that you showed me but the text that supposed to be in front of the image is breaking due to the closing div at the wrong place.

Comment: Can you add the expected html ouput to your question, to get a more accurated idea.